# Conditional electric switch based on two power sources

Tags: switches

Is there any available electric switch in the market for which the following condition satisfies?

It has two power sources, `src1` and `src2`. It outputs `src1` when both `src1` and `src2` are available. Otherwise, there's no output.

Comment: A microcontroller and a relay is the obvious solution.

Comment: "Being available" doesn't mean there is sufficient power or voltage to activate anything. What does "no output" actually mean?

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQhP0P.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A simple relay will suffice.*

How it works:

- If SRC2 is off then OUT is off.
- If SRC2 is on the OUT will be SRC1.

You are looking for a relay.

- The coil voltage should match SRC2's voltage.
- The contact voltage rating should be greater than or equal to SRC1 voltage.
- The contact current rating should be greater than or equal to the load current and DC or AC as appropriate.

Comment: Yes exactly what I want. Is there any product in market with a specific name for this switch? For example, there are [Residual-current Devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual-current_device)?

P.S. Sorry I don't come from engineering background.

Comment: See the update. Residual current devices are for detection of ground or earth faults in a circuit and are not appropriate for this application.

Comment: Yes, the purpose of linking `Residual current devices` was to indicate that a device for some specific purpose exists in market and we can purchase it. I am not sure if I can purchase [this](https://www.circuitlab.com/editor/#?id=s78rgvxrdtkq).

Comment: You might as well have linked to a picture of a hammer. They exist for some specific purpose and you can purchase it but it is no good in your application. Yes, relays exist. They are used in vehicles, industry and various control systems. Note that you cannot ask for product recommendations or where to buy them on this site.